# Objective-C: How do I access parent private properties from subclasses?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7

```
//Super class .h file

@interface MySuperClass : NSObject

@end

//Super class .m file

@interface MySuperClass ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *emailField; 

@end

@implementation MySuperClass

-(void)accessMyEmailField {

   NSLog(@"My super email: %@", self.emailField.text);

}

@end


// ********** my subclass *******

//Subclass .h file

@interface MySubClass : MySuperClass

@end

//SubClass .m file

@interface MySubClass ()

@end

@implementation MySubClass

-(void)myEmail {

   NSLog(@"My subclass email: %@", self.emailField.text);

}

-(void)setMyEmailFromSubclass{

   self.emailField.Text = @"email@gmail.com"

}

@end
```

1. How do i access emailField in `-(void)myEmail method`.
2. How do i set email in Subclass `-(void)setMyEmailFromSubclass`; , and access it in super class `accessMyEmailField`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put accessors to these properties in a second header file, and import that file on a 'need-to-know' basis..
eg

mySuperClass+undocumentedProperties.h

```
#import "mySuperClass.h"

@interface mySuperClass(undocumentedProperties)

  @property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *emailField;

 @end
```

mySuperClass.m

```
#import "mySuperClass+undocumentedProperties.h"

@interface mySuperClass()
///stuff that truly will be private to this class only
// self.emailField is no longer declared here..
@end

@implementation mySuperClass

@synthesize emailField; //(not really needed anymore)

/// etc, all your code unaltered
@end
```

mySubclass.h

```
#import "mySuperClass.h"
@interface mySubclass:mySuperClass

///some stuff
@end
```

mySubclass.m

```
#import "mySubclass.h"
#import "mySuperClass+undocumentedProperties.h"
@implementation

//off you go, this class is now 'aware' of this secret inherited property..

@end
```

obviously MySuperClass.m will have to import this .h file as well as its default one (or actually instead of, the default one is built in to this one), but your subclasses can import it too (directly into their .m file, so these properties remain private to the class.  This is not a proper category because there is no corresponding mySuperClass+undocumentedProperties.m file (if you tried that you could not synthesize the backing iVars for these secret properties.  Enjoy :)

Comment: Its little unclear for me. Can you show how would you do in the example i provided.

Comment: If I had just one class that needed access inside, I would tend just to put this info inside the other class just to reduce the number of files.  But if it's more than one that needs semi-private access this is really the best solution.

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner Thanks. Learned something new today.

Comment: also Pasha, this might or might not be bleeding obvious, but there could just as easily be undocumented methods/function prototypes in this 'secret header' for the subclasses to see 

e.g. 
-(void)do something; 

etc

Comment: Well, this is a concept similar to what i use, and sometimes is not clear at first especially if coming from other oop languages what one needs to re-declare and how to access superclass props and members. Like Zaph explained "private" member should always stay "private" and never visible outside of the scope of its base class. And if we are accessing "super" member from its subclass - that should remain hidden from outer world - we would need something that is called "PROTECTED" member visibility in other oop languages. Still i didn't found a clean and nice way to replicate in Objective-C

Comment: Yes I agree. Still, I have it on good authority that this is exactly what they do at 1 infinite loop....

Answer (score 1):

Copy the private interface portion of the methods you want from your superclass - or in other words, in your Subclass.m file you would put:

```
@interface MySuperClass ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *emailField; 
@end
```

( place it above the existing `@interface MySubClass ()` code )

Now your subclass knows that method exists in the superclass and can use it, but you are not exposing it to anyone else.

Comment: But this is a terrible concept! They can be deleted or substantially changed. The super class should not be dependent on a subclass but that is exactly what this causes, the super class can not change it's internal implementation without changing subclasses that use them.

Comment: In .m subclass ('@interface MySubClass () @property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *emailField; @end') This way i can set superclass property, but then in superclass my emailField still empty

Comment: Zaph: I just said how, not if you should.  @Pasha: you probably are trying to set emailField before it gets set by IB or viewDidLoad or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of private properties is exactly that and you should not want to access them. Because they are private they can change or be removed thus breaking the subclass that relies on them.

That being said they are not really private, just not "published". The can be called because Objective-C is a run-time dynamic language.

Comment: Thats exactly what i'm trying to do. I don't want make emailField to be published, thats why i'm keeping it in .m file, but i need to access it from subclass .m file

Comment: If they are both your classes create two header files. One with the public declarations, another with the private declarations. Import the private and public in the superclass and in any subclass that needs it but do not make the private header available to others. This is what Apple does to handle it public and private methods.